# Caching of jpg files fails in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm using a minimal Ubuntu server 16.04 with Nginx 1.10.3 (to which I moved from Apache 2 days ago). On this environment, I run a minimal Wordpress site (5 plugins, no customization).

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d;
}

location ~* \.(pdf)$ {
    expires 30d;
}
```

I pasted that code inside the server block in the `default.conf` file of Nginx (to use it with other sites if I'd need), and restarted:

```
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Yet when running GPI test I still get “Leverage browser caching” for many jpg files, even though “jpg” is already included in the directive.

All documentation I found, so far, deals exactly with what I already tried. Any ideas? Maybe most doc is outdated? Maybe that’s a bug in the current release of Nginx?

Comment: "to which I moved from Apache" means he moved from Apache to nginx.

Comment: What is the complete `default.conf`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Benqzq/5e21d720d0dbbc3ba94991ed5bd8ebb8

Comment: Browser caching uses a bunch of headers, I suspect the expires directive only affects one of them. Can you please do "curl -i http://contfix.co.il"  (or to whatever your main domain is that doesn't forward" and edit your question to include the response headers?

Comment: When I do `curl -i contfix.co.il` I get the enitre HTML and CSS of the webpage, That's basically all I get - tons of HTML and CSS.

Comment: Adding "| more" would've shown you the headers, paginated. I really needed a jpeg header anyway. I did it myself and your server isn't sending [any headers that affect caching at all](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170814_VZ_d12227499e1538ced4cb8ca1190debb0/). Please edit your question to include your full server configuration - ie the Nginx server blocks serving this site.

Comment: Sure Tim. Here they are: [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/Benqzq/5c15513e4cb5dfb1d6265b2d56f92e85), [default.conf](https://gist.github.com/Benqzq/fcc3379eceba55ff586da896c8e8ba31), [domain.tld.conf](https://gist.github.com/Benqzq/4128de9ee4bcba45c71b2e400521aeb3); BTW, I executed `curl -i contfix.co.il | more` in Bash but again I got a gigantic output of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the cache expiration directive in the `server` block instead of the `http` block.

I Putted the code in the end of the site-conf server block, rstarted Nginx and GPI test no logner showed the notification.

```
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

} # domain.tld.conf server block closure.
```

Comment: How does this differ from your original configuration? When I look at that it looks like it's in the server block in the original config, and your answer. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: I edited to make the answer more accurate and clear.